# IF Sumproduct issues on staggered columns

Tags: excel-formula

[ExcelFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i8xc.png)

In the picture above I am trying to get an "OK" to populate in column AL when there is a "O" or "N/A", in any of the judgement columns  N,S,X,AC,AH.  This is what I wrote but it won't return the values.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(((N9:AH9="O")+(N9:AH9="N/A"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AH),5)=4))=6,"OK","")
```

I am sure this is just something I am missing but any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for a total of **6** but you are only looking at 5 columns. Even if they all matched you would only get a total of **5**. Your narrative seems like you want an **OK** *'when there is a "O" or "N/A", in any of the judgement columns'* so you only need a total that is greater than zero.

Comment: Sorry poor explanation.  I need either a "O" or "N/A" in all the columns to get the "OK"

Comment: Just change the **=6** to  **=5**.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a total of 6 but you are only looking at 5 columns. Even if they all matched you would only get a total of 5.

In an unused column on row 9 use this portion of the formula,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((N9:AH9="O")+(N9:AH9="N/A"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AH),5)=4))
```

That will output the numerical total matches. Filling the intermediate columns with anything (even **O** or **N/A**) will not raise the total but filling in one of the N, S, X, AC or AH cells will if it is filled in with either **O** or **N/A**.

A simple adjustment for the total matches that you are looking for should be sufficient to get the IF formula working.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(((N9:AH9="O")+(N9:AH9="N/A"))*(MOD(COLUMN(N:AH),5)=4))=5,"OK","")
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  "DOH"  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't catch that before asking you to start a new question but I didn't catch the 5 column in N:AH until I saw the situatioj in its entirety.